# Merge “modal” and “modal-dialog” tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Per the instructions in [How to suggest tags to be merged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92043/161858) can someone please merge  [modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal) and [modal-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog)? I'd start re-tagging them myself, but this would take more time than I have.

- [modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal) ×5968
- [modal-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog) ×4211

Modal is defined as "Modal windows are child windows that require user interaction before closing and allowing the user to return to the parent window". Modal-dialog is defined as "Refers to a graphical dialog used to display important information to the user. These dialogs appear above all other content, blocking application flow until user input is received."

Judging by the slight difference in question tag totals, I'd suggest merging modal-dialog into modal, but wouldn't mind the other way. I would've suggested a synonym, but I don't have the privileges.